# Tensorflow create new tensor from indices

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to combine tensors in the following way:

```
a = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2]
b = [[1, 2], [3, 4], 
     [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], 
     [11, 12]]
```

output:

```
c = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], 
     [[5, 6], [7, 8] ,[9, 10]], 
     [[11, 12]]]
```

So essentially a is the indices of tensor b in the second dimension.

Shapes are as follows:

```
a = (?,) #(6) in this example
b = (?, 2) #(6, 2) in this example
c = (?, ?, 2) #(batch_size aka 3, varies, maybe I need a ragged tensor, 2)
```

Longer explanation:
I am trying to filter a tensor while maintaining the original batch size. When I run the following the above is the simplified output:

```
pos = tf.where(box_class_scores >= confidence)
g_boxes =  tf.gather_nd(boxes, pos) # this is b
indicies = tf.cast(pos[:, 0], tf.float32) #this is a
```

I need to do the above to maintain the batch size for the model. I am using Tensorflow 1.14 (this is a requirement)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the constructor of a ragged tensor for anyone else searching for this:

```
tf.RaggedTensor.from_value_rowids(
    values=b,
    value_rowids=a)
```